# How to create orphan (unrelated) branch with GitHub Actions

Tags: git, github, github-actions

I have branch `production` in my repo what triggering `build` Action (to build all my TypeScript code).
Build script saves /dist (/build) folders as artifact, but I also want to create/update new branch named `production-build` where I put all built code to be able to pull it later into production server.

Sure I can just put all my built code directly onto production server with Action script, but then I lost partial pulls and I am forced to "delete and unpack new" on all production files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://github.com/marketplace/actions/github-pages-action#%EF%B8%8F-force-orphan

You can use the page above as a reference for github action to make an orphan branch when the build is completed.

> Force orphan We can set the force_orphan: true option. This allows
>   you to make your publish branch with only the latest commit.

```
- name: Deploy   uses: peaceiris/actions-gh-pages@v3   with:
     github_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
     publish_dir: ./public
     force_orphan: true
```

Comment: Nice! Exactly what I needed, but I am not really sure how to set the branch name, is it `publish`? Or it will push into current branch the Action is running from.

Comment: it would deploy to the gh-pages branch

Comment: Any way to change it? :D

Comment: https://github.com/actions/checkout

here's a nudge in the right direction ;)

Comment: I mean, change name of the new created branch, not checkout into branch :D

Comment: I see it now... `publish_branch: master`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple example of a YAML workflow to set a custom branch as a deployment target.

```yaml
- name: Deploy
  uses: peaceiris/actions-gh-pages@v3
  with:
    github_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
    publish_dir: ./out                # default: public
    publish_branch: production-build  # default: gh-pages
    force_orphan: true
```

By enabling the `force_orphan`, it keeps the latest commit only.

For more options and usages, see the latest README on our repo: [peaceiris/actions-gh-pages: GitHub Actions for GitHub Pages](https://github.com/peaceiris/actions-gh-pages)